# declare component to all routes react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i have a header and inside it i have Link components to navigate for any pages, and the header need show on all routes, i put Header component inside switch method because i have  component inside it. but the header componet is render alone, the other components not are rendered, only the header component.

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Switch>
                        <Header/>
                        <Route path={'/'} exact={true} component={Main}/>
                        <Route path={'/cursos'} exact={true} component={Cursos}/>
                        <Route path={'/forum'} exact={true} component={Forum}/>
                        <Route path={'/login'} exact={true} component={Login}/>
                    </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>
                <Footer/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```js
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <BrowserRouter>
                  <React.Fragment>
                    <Header/>
                    <Switch>                        
                        <Route path={'/'} exact={true} component={Main}/>
                        <Route path={'/cursos'} exact={true} component={Cursos}/>
                        <Route path={'/forum'} exact={true} component={Forum}/>
                        <Route path={'/login'} exact={true} component={Login}/>
                    </Switch>
                  </React.Fragment>
                </BrowserRouter>
                <Footer/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

`Switch` is designed to render only one child (the first that matches).

Comment: Its works, i will study more about React.Fragment, Thank you very much